# Avoid redundancy in formula in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Say I have a long expression (i.e. with a lot of characters) `expr`. I want to give a cell the formula `=if(expr>10,expr,0)` (this is an example, the condition could also be `=if(iserror(expr),expr,0)`).
Although the syntax is very simple, the expression can be very long and tedious to debug.

Would there be a way to "map" a function to expr, something like `=map(if(#>10,#,0),expr)`  (but of course `#` is not a appropriate) so that `expr` appears only once?

*Edit* Just to make the answer clear: it is not possible to map functions in such a way, using only Google Sheet's functions.